# sonar findbugs missing class exception

Tags: sonarqube

While I am using Sonar findbugs for code review, it throws an exception, claiming some classes are missing.

After some research, it's clear that the jars needed to build the project should be included in the pom.xml for Sonar's use.

To do that, Sonar official web site is suggesting to add dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/.../xwork-core.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, for me, it's still not working.

I am using Windows, would anyone please enlighten me on how to configure, especially the systempath?

Here is the pom.xml, for one module of the project:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DB</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
  <name>project1</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
      <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version><!--installed into .m2 folder, local repository, then refer it-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dep</groupId>
      <artifactId>dep1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib//asn.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>build-to/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>false</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your project already a maven project, or are you compiling things with ant or some other tool and then trying to get sonar to run against it?  Sonar Light mode can be tricky with very complex projects.  If you've got a multi-module project, i'd get the simplest project working under a local copy of sonar and then work towards adding more modules.

Additionally,  I would try copying the files locally to a different directory that does not step up from ${basedir}.  See if that helps.  So ${basedir}/lib/xwork-core.jar  something like that.

Perhaps for Sonar analysis, you can have a separate task copy the needed libraries to a temp folder that can be accessed appropriately, and then remove them once the analysis is complete.

Comment: mike, thanks for the response. Here it's not a maven project, and it's multi-module. i have tried either copy library jars to ${basedir}, or install into local maven repository, however, both failed.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the problem. The official documentation of sonar is actually wrong.
"mvn sonar:sonar" would invoke the maven sonar plugin 2.0 beta, which won't enable the dependency of library jars work. Instead, call "mvn sonar3:sonar", invoke the maven sonar plugin 2.4.1, the latest version, works.

Comment: Yes, if you're using Maven 3 you need to invoke sonar3.

Comment: do you mean, if it's maven 2, the command should be as "mvn sonar:sonar"? I think this command would invoke the maven-sonar-2.0-beta plugin, which was unable to make the dependency work. correct me, if i am wrong.